# setting the widget for cloudwatch dashboard. Getting the error "The dashboard body is invalid, there are 1 validation errors"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am not able to ref servicename in the widget.

Getting the following error with the given code: 
The dashboard body is invalid, there are 1 validation errors: [ { "dataPath": "/widgets/0/properties/metrics/0", "message": "Should NOT have more than 3 items" } ] (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterInput

```
"CloudwatchDashboard": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard",
      "Properties": {

"{ \"widgets\":
[{ \"type\":\"metric\", 
\"x\":0, 
\"y\":0, 
\"width\":12, 
\"height\":6, 
\"properties\":
{ \"metrics\":
[[ \"AWS/ECS\", \"CPUUtilization\", \"ServiceName\",
{ \"Fn::Sub\": [ \"${Service}\", { \"Service\": {\"Ref\" : \"AWS::StackName\" }} ]}]], 
\"region\": \"us-east-1\", 
\"stat\":\"Average\",
\"period\": 300, 
\"view\": \"timeSeries\", 
\"title\":\"CPUUtilization\", 
\"stacked\": false } }]}"

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard body is a string, so putting the `Sub` syntax inside that string is making it part of the dashboard definition which in turn makes it invalid.

I'd suggest switching to yaml syntax. This will allow you to keep your dashboard definition cleaner and you can use the `Sub` like this:

```
ExampleDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties: 
        DashboardName: 'SomeDashboard'
        DashboardBody: !Sub |
          {
              "widgets": [
                  {
                      "type": "metric",
                      "x": 0,
                      "y": 0,
                      "width": 12,
                      "height": 6,
                      "properties": {
                          "metrics": [
                              [ "AWS/ECS", "CPUUtilization", "ServiceName", "${AWS::StackName}"]
                          ],
                          "region": "us-east-1",
                          "stat": "Average",
                          "period": 300,
                          "view": "timeSeries",
                          "title": "CPUUtilization",
                          "stacked": false
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
```

Here is the same thing in json:

```
"ExampleDashboard": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard",
            "Properties": {
                "DashboardName": "SomeDashboard",
                "DashboardBody": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "{\n    \"widgets\": [\n        {\n            \"type\": \"metric\",\n            \"x\": 0,\n            \"y\": 0,\n            \"width\": 12,\n            \"height\": 6,\n            \"properties\": {\n                \"metrics\": [\n                    [ \"AWS/ECS\", \"CPUUtilization\", \"ServiceName\", \"${AWS::StackName}\"]\n                ],\n                \"region\": \"us-east-1\",\n                \"stat\": \"Average\",\n                \"period\": 300,\n                \"view\": \"timeSeries\",\n                \"title\": \"CPUUtilization\",\n                \"stacked\": false\n            }\n        }\n    ]\n}\n"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't change the format from JSON to YAML as JSON is the standard being used at my work in all projects. Do you know how to sub it in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your CloudWatch dashboards in JSON within your yaml templates as follows:

```yaml
  ExampleDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties: 
      DashboardName: 'SomeDashboard'
      DashboardBody: !Sub '
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 12,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/ECS", "CPUUtilization", "ServiceName", "${AWS::StackName}"]
                ],
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "stat": "Average",
                "period": 300,
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "title": "CPUUtilization",
                "stacked": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error: for future Googlers, the error is misleading! My problem was that I had accidentally lower-cased the whole widget, so it had e.g. `functionname` instead of `FunctionName`. Fixing the case let it deploy.