# How to use Parameters in CloudWatch Dashboard template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a `CloudFormation` template to create a `CloudWatch` dashboard. Following is the template code -

```
Parameters:
    MyEnvironment:
        Type: String
        Default: "do"
        Description: "Specifies the environment of the platform."
Resources:
    MyServiceDashboard:
        Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
        Properties:
            DashboardName: "Test-My-Dashboard"
            DashboardBody: >
                {
                    "widgets": [
                        {
                            "type": "metric",
                            "x": 15,
                            "y": 18,
                            "width": 6,
                            "height": 6,
                            "properties": {
                                "view": "timeSeries",
                                "stacked": false,
                                "metrics": [
                                    [ "AWS/Kinesis", "GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds", "StreamName", 
"${MyEnvironment}-my-data-out"
                                    ]...
```

I am trying to use `MyEnvironment` parameter which will be provided when I will actually use this template to create a stack.

Problem is stack/dashbaord gets created using this but the parameter value is not getting used in the Dashboard metric instead it uses value as `"${MyEnvironment}-my-data-out"` instead of `"Dev-my-data-out"` assuming I have provided `"MyEnvironment"` value as `"Dev"`

I tried the method specified in this link - [Use Pseudo Variables in Cloudwatch Dashboard Template (Cloudformation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878042/use-pseudo-variables-in-cloudwatch-dashboard-template-cloudformation) but CloudFormation shows invalid template when using `Sub >-` keyword.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616110/setting-the-widget-for-cloudwatch-dashboard-getting-the-error-the-dashboard-bo/56618152#56618152

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying various options, found the solution, **important** **point** is to use `!Sub` function otherwise parameter values are not replaced in the JSON string.

```
        DashboardName: "Test-My-Dashboard"
        DashboardBody: !Sub '{
                "widgets": [
```

Notice the !Sub function in the `DashboardBody` attribute. After this you can refer to parameter values by using `${PARAMETER_NAME}` format.

[!Sub function documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

Comment: Excellent life safer. I have spent almost 4hrs looking for this. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

"MyEnvironment" is not a pseudo variable. It is for AWS variables only like region. 
You need to use 'Ref' if you want to parameterize.

```
    Parameters:
MyEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Default: "do"
    Description: "Specifies the environment of the platform."
    Resources:
MyServiceDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
        DashboardName: "Test-My-Dashboard"
        DashboardBody: >
            {
                "widgets": [
                    {
                        "type": "metric",
                        "x": 15,
                        "y": 18,
                        "width": 6,
                        "height": 6,
                        "properties": {
                            "view": "timeSeries",
                            "stacked": false,
                            "metrics": [
                                [ "AWS/Kinesis", "GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds", "StreamName",  {"Ref" : "MyEnvironment"}

                              ]...
```

Pass "Dev-my-data-out" in the MyEnvironment parameter directly to avoid complication.

Comment: This does not work for me, Dashboard creation fails using this, and if I use escaped string then dashboard creation succeeds but uses the escaped string instead of parameter value.